# Trump vs Section 230

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, regulation, internet, social-media

I see that Trump is against [Section 230](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Section_230). As I understand it, it relieves social media platforms from the liability associated with the content shared by 3rd parties, which I think should enable free speech. But why is then [Trump against it](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2020/12/house-overrides-trump-veto-defying-demand-to-repeal-section-230/), if he's for free speech? Am I either not understanding the law or Trump's position on it?

Because if you want social media platforms to be liable for the content others use them to share, you are only forcing them to censor content. It does not "retaliate against Facebook and Twitter for their perceived bias against him".

Answer (score 6):

The controversial part of [Section 230](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/230) is (c):

> **(c)Protection for “Good Samaritan” blocking and screening of offensive
> material**
>
> - **(1)Treatment of publisher or speaker** No provider or user of
>   an *interactive computer service* shall be treated as the publisher or
>   speaker of any information provided by another *information content
>   provider*.
> - **(2)Civil liability** No provider or user of an *interactive computer
>   service* shall be held liable on account of—
> - - **(A)** any action voluntarily
>     taken in good faith to restrict access to or availability of material
>     that the provider or user considers to be obscene, lewd, lascivious,
>     filthy, excessively violent, harassing, or otherwise objectionable,
>     whether or not such material is constitutionally protected; or
> - - **(B)** any
>     action taken to enable or make available to *information content
>     providers* or others the technical means to restrict access to material
>     described in paragraph (1).[1](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/230)

And the associated definitions:

> **(2)Interactive computer service**
> The term “interactive computer service” means any information service, system, or access software provider that provides or enables computer access by multiple users to a computer server, including specifically a service or system that provides access to the Internet and such systems operated or services offered by libraries or educational institutions.
>
> **(3)Information content provider**
> The term “information content provider” means any person or entity that is responsible, in whole or in part, for the creation or development of information provided through the Internet or any other interactive computer service.

Effectively, what this is saying is that:

1. **The social media company does *not* count as the "speaker" for anything a user uploads to them - the user is.**  This prevents you from suing Twitter for defamation if someone tweets negative things about you, copyright infringement if someone uploads a movie, and so on.
2. **The social media company does not *become* the speaker if they edit/restrict/block something a user uploaded... *provided* that they're acting in good faith.**  Without this, Twitter can either claim to be unaware of the specific content in question, or they can make edits to/restrict/remove it, in which case they clearly were aware of it and intentionally chose to distribute it (and thus become liable as the publisher/speaker of the content).

Trump (and other conservative voices) want to change #2 so that the social media companies would *not* be allowed to "restrict their free speech" by labeling or removing content.  The problem is that without the protections from #2, social media companies have to choose between:

1. Provide no filters whatsoever.
2. Filter content before it gets uploaded.
3. Get sued for publishing inappropriate/illegal/offensive material.
4. Remove all content searching and only show content that the user specifically opted to see.  (i.e. you could see the posts from a user you chose to follow, but no replies unless they're by a user you also follow. You could only be contacted by a user whom you chose to let contact you. And so on.)

[This Ars Technica article](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2020/06/section-230-the-internet-law-politicians-love-to-hate-explained/) goes into more detail about where Section 230 came from, some proposed changes, and what the implications of them are.

Comment: There's a 4th option, provide users with the option to filter.

Comment: @Ryan_L - I considered adding that, but then you would have to decide what options to give the user to filter _on_.  Do you rely on (for example) which hashtags the uploader used and trust that they're honest about them?  Or do you automatically try to apply tags, which puts you right back in the category of 3, because you're adding something.  I suppose making everything opt-in could be an option, at the cost of a severe hit to usability.

Comment: @Ryan_L - I added a fourth option, but it really cripples the _social_ part of _social media_.

Comment: I wonder if the jury system on Minds.com would work.  I don't know all the details, but users are randomly selected to be a jury and rule on individual cases for moderator intervention.  So it's not official Minds employees banning or deleting, it's the users.

Comment: @Ryan_L - Probably not.  The moment that a user is exposed to something that they object to and are asked to judge it, the provider can be sued for showing it to them.  Unless they opt in to moderating like that, and thereby intentionally open themselves up to it... at which point the spammers and trolls just start uploading thousands and thousands of copies of junk to overwhelm the moderators.

Comment: The problem is that "objectionable" and "in good faith" are subjective.  When first written, section 230 was geared toward what any rational person would consider lewd, obscene, violent, etc., and service providers were given an "out" to filter blatant child porn and other obvious bad stuff.  Now, in our snowflake-riddled world, these platforms have taken the S230 meaning of "objectionable" to it's wildest extent, resulting in outright blocking of views deemed unpopular, controversial, or simply in conflict with the provider's viewpoint.  This is the problem with subjective legalize.

Comment: @mikem Twitter has a first amendment right to apply its own definition of _objectionable_ to its own platform.  In other words, Twitter has a first amendment right to be a snowflake.

Comment: Agreed, but at that point, they become a publisher and should lose section 230 protection.  No one is saying they can't filter content, but when they do and it's purely for their own gain, ie. not simply "in good faith" to protect against lewd & obscene content, but rather to push or prohibit certain viewpoints, then their protection under s230 comes into question.

Comment: @mikem - You have that backwards.  Section 230 says that they _don't_ become a publisher.  Losing its protection would mean that they do.  And unless they do, they're not responsible for the content.  Also, where do you draw the line?  There are religions (plural) which consider some body parts to be obscene to have uncovered.  Should all pictures of someone's elbow be banned because someone considers them obscene?  Should all pictures of someone's bare chest be banned (regardless of apparent gender)?  Should all pictures of someone's groin be banned?

Comment: 230 protects them so that they are not considered a publisher as long as they don't control the content, or so long as they only act in good faith.  Once they break those lines, they have become a publisher and would/should lose 230 protections.  As far as where the line is, that's the problem with subjectivity as I mentioned before.  Lewd and obscene are fairly well established in American culture, from a majority standpoint... it's still a bell curve and there are the fringes.  But, when we are talking about ideas and viewpoints, it's hard to get to lewd/obscene just because you disagree.

Comment: @mikem content doesn't have to be lewd or obscene to trigger (c)(2)(A), it can also be "otherwise objectionable."  And Twitter has a first amendment right to decide that content that undermines the US constitution is objectionable.  But flagging a tweet probably doesn't fall under (c)(2)(A) or (c)(2)(B) because it restricts neither access to nor availability of the tweet.  Furthermore, these conditions apply to civil liability, but they do not affect (c)(1).  Therefore the assertion that Twitter's editorializing allows Twitter to be treated as a publisher is incorrect.

Comment: No one is saying they don't have the right to edit the content on their site (edit = block/alter/etc).  They certainly have the right, but and again, the problem is with the subjectivity of the statute.  In their OPINION, some content might undermine the US constitution, but it is nothing more than their opinion.  And they certainly have the right to use their opinion to determine what they consider objectionable.  The point is, when they do so, they are now an editor of the content on their site... not just moderating "in good faith", and have become a publisher.

Comment: @mikem nothing in the law causes them to become a publisher under any circumstances.  The law simply states without condition "No provider or user of an interactive computer service shall be treated as the publisher or speaker of any information provided by another information content provider."  The conditions in (c)(2) do not apply to (c)(1).

Comment: I suppose if it ever makes it to a court challenge, then we'll know the answer.

Comment: @mikem - Based on some of the content [on this EFF page](https://www.eff.org/issues/bloggers/legal/liability/230) and pages it links to, I think courts have interpreted "good faith" to mean "you aren't making it look like someone is saying something they aren't".  In other words, it's perfectly valid to edit a comment to fix `is nto broken` to `is not broken`, but it'd be a violation of good faith to instead edit it to just `is broken`, because that changes the meaning.  There may be a more specific ruling to point to - I didn't look at every case listed.  And I may still be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Let me begin by saying your read of the situation is correct, and there is no plausible way that repealing Section 230 would lead to an increase in free speech on the Internet. Other answers have given good explanations of why that is, but your explanation is basically correct: increasing liability for user content will lead Internet companies to censor more user content. That's basic economics. Indeed, liberals who support Section 230 repeal like [Beto O'Rourke](https://www.theverge.com/2019/8/16/20808839/beto-orourke-section-230-communications-decency-act-2020-president-democrat-background-checks) and [Joe Biden](https://www.politico.com/news/2020/01/17/joe-biden-tech-liability-shield-revoked-facebook-100443) do so *because* they support an increase in social media censorship of speech they don't like, specifically hate speech and election misinformation respectively.

> But why is then Trump against it, if he's for free speech? Am I either not understanding the law or Trump's position on it?

There is a third possible option here, namely that Trump's public position is not built on actual principle at all.

Section 230 has existed for decades, the repeal movement for a few years, but Trump's crusade against it began on a very specific date, May 28, 2020, when he [issued](https://www.whitehouse.gov/presidential-actions/executive-order-preventing-online-censorship/) an "Executive Order on Preventing Online Censorship." The following day, he sent his first ever anti-Section 230 tweets.

[image]

Two days earlier, May 26, marked the [first time](https://www.cnn.com/2020/05/27/app-politics-section/donald-trump-mail-in-voter-fraud-fact-check/index.html) that Twitter had slapped a disclaimer on a Trump tweet.

[image]

The White House executive order was pretty explicit that the order was being issued in response to Twitter's actions:

> Twitter now selectively decides to place a warning label on certain
> tweets in a manner that clearly reflects political bias.  As has been
> reported, Twitter seems never to have placed such a label on another
> politician’s tweet.  As recently as last week, Representative Adam
> Schiff was continuing to mislead his followers by peddling the
> long-disproved Russian Collusion Hoax, and Twitter did not flag those
> tweets.  Unsurprisingly, its officer in charge of so-called ‘Site
> Integrity’ has flaunted his political bias in his own tweets.

So if it seems to you through a plain reading of Section 230 that the actual effect of its repeal would be to stifle speech at great cost to Twitter, or to force Twitter to shutter completely... consider that might be the point?

Comment: You might consider replacing "force Twitter to shutter completely" with "bite the hand that feeds you."

Comment: I feel this answer, while good, would be made better with an explicit spelling out bob's point, that the conservatives' complaint isn't that 230 protects social media from being sued but rather that it allows 'good faith' filtering when the conservatives want to force social media to never filter or restrict anything.  A quick paragraph at the top explaining that distinction would make an already good answer an exceptional one.

Answer (score 3):

There are several different things going on here. Let's start by going through [the text of section 230](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/230):

- (c)(1) says that a social media company (or other "provider of an interactive computer service") cannot be held responsible for the contents of user-generated content. Without section 230, courts would generally hold companies that moderate their content to a higher standard than companies that do not so moderate, according to prior case law. Under (c)(1), *nobody* can be held responsible for content they did not create. This also applies to things like retweets, because the liability shield is also extended to users.
- Various social media companies are banning certain people from posting certain things, and/or labeling the postings as false or misleading. They have a First Amendment right to do that, assuming the "this is false or misleading" labels are substantially true (and therefore not libelous). Section 230 (c)(2) additionally says that social media sites cannot be held responsible for this sort of removal when it is done "in good faith," but it's unclear why they would be liable for it in the first place. There is no cause of action that allows the President (or anyone else) to force a private company to publish something the company does not wish to publish, and most of them also have terms of service explicitly empowering them to remove any content they like.
  Some people read (c)(2) as reinforcing (c)(1), as if it's saying "(c)(1) still applies even if the content is moderated," but this would render it [surplusage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surplusage) because (c)(1) is already a categorical statement with no exception for moderation. Courts normally try to avoid rendering part of a law redundant, so I'm skeptical that a court would read it that way. Instead, (c)(2) more naturally reads as an entirely separate liability shield for moderation actions.
- There has been much discussion of "publishers" vs "platforms," alleging that section 230 only applies to a neutral "platform" rather than a partisan or non-neutral "publisher." There is no language in the text which in any way supports this reading. Many on the right want to add a restriction like this, but it's not currently in the law as written. Repealing the law would have a *similar* effect, but as described above, instead of distinguishing between "publishers" and "platforms," it would distinguish between "sites that moderate content" and "sites that don't."

Comment: @WS2: Anonymous speech has [always been permitted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_which_is_not_forbidden_is_allowed). It just used to be difficult. But not impossible; a newspaper could always publish an anonymous letter to the editor, if it so chose.

Comment: See also [*McIntyre v. Ohio Elections Commission*](https://www.oyez.org/cases/1994/93-986) for the status of anonymous speech under US law.

Comment: @WS2 While your account has a picture, I don't see any name given, making your comment in response to someone who at least shared their first name a bit hypocritical. Anonymous speech is essential in a democracy.

Comment: @Kevin and one can post anonymous notices in public places.

Comment: @Acccumulation Your point is well taken. What I meant was that none of the documents gave anyone the right to slander anonymously. I will delete my comment. It was badly worded. It is another matter if there is a public interest, where whistle-blowers clearly have to be protected. But there was a dreadful case in the UK where a professional footballer was reported to be having an affair (not a matter of "public interest", though it does "interest the public" - two different things). And the people making the allegations, and newspapers protecting sources, refused to say who was making them.

Comment: @Acccumulation And the further problem is that anonymity  has now become such an endemic part of our modern electronic communications culture that we all tend to do it.  And with increasing anonymity it has removed a whole area of responsibility for what is said.

Answer (score -6):

Section 230 doesn't unconditionally protect internet companies from liability, it only does so if they are platforms, not publishers.  By deleting posts, adding disclaimers and fact-check warnings, and banning users for legal speech, they are acting like publishers, not platforms.

Comment: [Source?](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/47/230) The section mentions "platform" never, and "publisher" once, which is where it says that (for example) Twitter shall not be treated as the publisher of what Donald Trump says. That's it. That's all it says. It doesn't say anything about "acting like publishers, not platforms"

Comment: @user253751 - Section 230 uses the term "Interactive computer service" for the companies - "platform" is a much newer term for them.

Comment: @Bobson I think you'll have a hard time arguing that Twitter isn't an interactive computer service just because it bans you if you post fake news. Those words have *meanings*.

Comment: @user253751 - Yes, that's my point. "Platform = Interactive computer service".  Pointing out that the text doesn't use the word "platform" (as per your comment) isn't really a relevant criticism.

Comment: @Bobson if Twitter was a publisher by your definition, it would still be an interactive computer service, no?

Comment: @user253751 Funny how the fake news bannings only go one way.  Nobody at the New York Times was banned for what they said about Nick Sandmann.

Comment: @Ryan_L I think you'll have a hard time arguing that Twitter isn't an interactive computer service just because it only bans you for posting fake news if you're right-wing.

Comment: @user253751 The problem is that they violate the "Good Samaritan" part.  Professor Sarah Parcak can tweet instructions to topple the Washington Monument, but rapper ZUBY gets banned for saying "Ok, dude".  Kathy Griffin can hold up Donald Trump's severed head, but you'll get banned for telling a journalist to "Learn to code".  In what world is any of this being a "Good Samaritan"?

Comment: @Ryan_L the law doesn't say anything about good samaritans, that's just a headline. Read the actual law please. Neither (1)(C)(1) nor (1)(C)(2) says they become liable for bad stuff people post if they aren't good samaritans.

Comment: @user253751 It says they can remove things "in good faith".  How is banning people for saying "Learn to code" while not banning Kathy Griffin for holding up Donald Trump's severed head "good faith"?  How is suspending ZUBY for saying "Ok, dude", while not suspending any journalists for what they said about Nick Sandmann "good faith"?

Comment: @Ryan_L - That's the point of Section 230.  There's nothing there about being balanced or fair, or even consistent.  It's protection against being sued for what they _do_, not what they _don't do_.  As a private corporation, they are free to apply whatever policy they want, whenever they want, however they want.  They can't be sued for leaving things up (they didn't create it), and they can't be sued for taking it down.

Comment: @Bobson then where does "good faith" come in?

Comment: @Ryan_L It says they are not liable for removing things in good faith. It doesn't say they can't remove things in bad faith, and it also doesn't say they'll be liable for doing so.

Comment: @user253751 Then why bring up good faith at all?  If they can't be held liable whether the actions are in good faith or not, why bring it up?  The explicit allowance of good faith editing tells me that there must be some editing that's not allowed.  How much can you edit someone else's posts before it becomes your own?

Comment: @Ryan_L This law doesn't says they are not liable for things they do in bad faith. Nor does it say they *are* liable. This law simply *has no effect at all* if the thing is done in bad faith. There may be another law which makes them liable for something they do in bad faith, and this law does not shield them. But this law does shield them from the other law if they do it in good faith.

Comment: @Ryan_L My understanding of "good faith" just means that they genuinely believe that it is something that should be removed.  Which _is_ generally pretty meaningless, but probably means that if they are sued, they have to actually claim that they found the material objectionable in order to get the protections of Section 230.

Comment: This answer misinterprets the law. As 230(c)(1) applies to Twitter, it says that Twitter is not to be treated as the publisher or speaker of content provided by its users.  That paragraph is about what Twitter _is._  On the other hand, 230(c)(2) says that Twitter is not to be held liable for restricting access to objectionable material under certain conditions.  That is about what Twitter _does_ and _how_ Twitter does it, but it has no bearing on the question of what Twitter _is._  Regardless of what Twitter does in respect of the conditions in 230(c)(2), it is not a publisher under 230(c)(1).

Comment: @Ryan_L - As per the comment I just made on my own answer, after looking into it a bit more, I think "good faith" actually means (or has been interpreted to mean) "not _changing_ what people say".  As long as whatever edits are made doesn't change the meaning (and outright removal doesn't), that's "good faith".  But IANAL and I may still be wrong.